# access via spring injected property which references a directory to access its files

Tags: java, windows, spring, tomcat, osgi

I'm trying to access a property defined in a bean like this:

```
<bean id="reportdepositService" class="a.b.c.ServiceImpl">
    <property name="reportDeposit" value="/WebContent/WEB-INF/dirName/" />
</bean>
```

ServiceImpl class looks like this:

```
public class ServiceImpl implements IService {

private Resource springResource;
public Resource getSpringResource() {
    return springResource;
}

public void setSpringResource(Resource springResource) {
    this.springResource = springResource;
}

private File getSpringResourceFile() throws IOException{
    Resource r = getSpringResource();
    URL url = FileLocator.resolve(r.getURL());
    return FileUtils.toFile(url);
}

public void doSomething(){

.. some logic .
File f = getSpringResourceFile();

}
```

executing that code within eclipse on a ubuntu machine works fine, application build on a jenkins works fine as well on ubuntu. Running that application on a win7/64, the code throws the following exception:

```
   OSGi resource[/WebContent/WEB-INF/springResource/|bnd.id=332|bnd.sym=a.b.server] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist
java.io.FileNotFoundException: OSGi resource[/WebContent/WEB-INF/springResource/|bnd.id=332|bnd.sym=a.b.server] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.osgi.io.OsgiBundleResource.getURL(OsgiBundleResource.java:228)
```

What is necessary to access the property on windows hosted system?
Any ideas? 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether you are on the correct road with this:

The /WebContent/WEB-INF path suggests that you are writing a web application to be run in a web container. In that case you should *never* assume that your resource is a file. You should open the resource using `Resource.getInputStream()` in stead of using the URL/File. The reason is that the the application may well be run directly from the .war without a file system being available.

That may immediately answer the question: is the Windows 7 environment the same in relation to the run-enviroment? My impression is that it is not. If you bundled the project into a bundle jar while transporting it to the windows machine, I guess you should add a prefix to the path (but probably need to leave the WebContent off), like bundle:, classpath:, etc. See [Spring OSGI](http://docs.spring.io/osgi/docs/current/reference/html/bnd-app-ctx.html) reference. But you need to give a little more information to be sure.